# How prove this series $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos{(k!\theta)}$ is bounded or unbounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series

prove or disprove:

> the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos{(k!\theta)}$$ bounded?
>   where
>   $0<\theta<2\pi,\theta\neq\dfrac{p}{q}\pi,(p,q)=1,p,q\in N^{+}$

My idea:  we can only prove 
$$\cos{(n!)}$$ is dense on $(0,1]$? is good try?

Thank you .

Comment: Even if you showed that $\cos(k!\theta)$ has the same distribution as $\cos(X)$ for uniformly random $X \in (0, 2\pi)$, that would not imply a bound.

Comment: I wonder if this sort of thing should be solved using [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Answer (score 4):

It is not bounded for $\theta=2\,\pi(e-2)$, which satisfies all the required conditions, since $e$ is irrational and $0<e-2<1$. Let's prove it. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{align}
n!(e-2)&=K_n+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\dots\\
&\le K_n+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}+\dots\\
&=K_n+\frac{1}{n},
\end{align}$$
where $K_n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then
$$
0\le n!\theta-2\,\pi\,K_n\le \frac{2\,\pi}{n}
$$
and
$$
\cos(n!\theta)=\cos(n!\theta-2\,\pi\,K_n)\ge\cos\Bigl(\frac{2\,\pi}{n}\Bigr).
$$
Since $\cos(2\,\pi/n)\to1$ ans $n\to\infty$, the sum is unbounded.

### Edit

The same argument will work for $\theta=2\,\pi\,\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is irrational, $0<\alpha<1$ and
$$
\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!},\quad a_n\in\mathbb{Z},\quad\sup|a_n|<\infty.
$$

Comment: Thank you,Now maybe  this $\theta$ have many infinite number such this sum unbounded?and How prove it?

Comment: The same argument will prove that the sum is unbounded if $\theta=2\,\pi\text{fractional part}(k-e)$ for $k=3,4,5\dots$.